# What is the best way to sync data between 2 Neo4j databases?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Currently we have 2 Neo4j databases in our application. We use Spring Data Neo4j (SDN).

First database is our STAGING database, and the other is LIVE database. This is more for the purpose of Versioning and to prevent user messing up LIVE database.

We have about 50.000 nodes and 150.000 relationships. Our STAGING area is meant for small subset of users, and we allow doing CRUD operations only in STAGING. After the user has finalized/verified the data in STAGING, we will push the dataset to LIVE database.
LIVE is only meant for READ ONLY database, CRUD is only allowed during the sync process.

I am wondering what's the best way to sync data between both databases and the sync should allow incremental updates.

I tried to do sync node by node using Cypher Query + SDN, but I hit a roadblock, it takes way too long.

```
@Query("START n=node:ItemCode('code:*') "
     + "WHERE has(n.status) AND n.status = 'ACTIVE') "
     + "RETURN n");
public Iterable<Item> getAllActiveItems();
```

On **SyncService** class which does the sync process from STAGING to LIVE db:

```
Iterable<Item> items = stagingRepo.getAllActiveItems();
for(Item item:items) {

    Item item = liveRepo.findItem(item.getCode());
    if(item == null) {
        //create item
    } else {
        //update item
    }
}
```

[UPDATE] Based on answer by [Peter Neubauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83490/peter-neubauer), I would like to explore further if there is Database Link concept so that the Cypher query can run on two databases at one go.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,
Gunawan

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Unfortunately this website is for programming questions only. Your question, however, is about database administration. You should rather post it on dba.stackexchange.com. That being said: Did you try to just copy the database on the filesystem layer?

Comment: Btw, it's related to programming question. I couldn't copy the db files to sync between databases as there is a requirement to do partial sync (only on certain nodes, e.g. Nodes with ACTIVE status) anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm running into the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can do the find and the update in one Cypher query and execute it in the `neo4jTemplate.query("....", params)` function?

If you use the code above, all matching stuff has to be materialized form the database into `Item` object and then saved again in your repo functions, creating that overhead.

Maybe a simple

```
START n=node:ItemCode('code:*')
WHERE has(n.status) AND n.status = 'ACTIVE')
WITH n
SET n.updated=1
```

and one for the new items would do the job? That way, the work is done in the DB and does not touch the SDN mapping layers.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will try to fire the query instead of converting back to Java object. By any chance, is there a way to have a query to create and update at the same time based on the node existence?

Comment: Found this [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-merge.html#merge-merge-using-unique-constraints-creates-a-new-node-if-no-node-is-found) command